# Theme Section for Google Ads in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How Can I add a section for Google Ads for my theme using WordPress Customizer API? I tried using adding textarea with add_control add_setting in a section but it did not work.

Comment: It would be better if you create a widget for such section and call it for the specific location where you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was trying to put it on the header section above the menu. That's why I need to use Customizer because it would be mess to put a widget on the header section for header ads.

Comment: It's okay you can completely design the look and feel for your widget.

Comment: Thank You For the help. Appreciate that a lot.